# Angular not able to generate component through nx console > generate

Tags: angular

```
 *  Executing task: npx ng generate @schematics/angular:component square --project=myTicTacToe --inline-style --inline-template --no-interactive 

EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/myName/myTicTacToe/src/app/square'

 *  The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'npx ng generate @schematics/angular:component square --project=myTicTacToe --inline-style --inline-template --no-interactive'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. `\
```

I was wondering why i can't generate my component with the inline template and the inline style -- ticked.

I had openned up my terminal to type

```
myName@myName-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo npx ng generate @schematics/angular:component square --project=myTicTacToe --inline-style --inline-template --no-interactive
```

and still nothing. I was wondering if anyone has experienced this problem as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` to generate your nx workspace? Then you can probably fix it using `sudo chown -R myName:myName /Users/myName/MyTicTacToe`...